# i argument in data.table (expression that evaluates to logical)

Tags: r, group-by, subset, data.table

i have the following:

```
test <- data.table(id=1:11, t=c(rep(1:2,5), 3))
test[length(unique(id))>1,list(id, t), by=t]

    id t
 1:  1 1
 2:  2 2
 3:  3 1
 4:  4 2
 5:  5 1
 6:  6 2
 7:  7 1
 8:  8 2
 9:  9 1
10: 10 2
11: 11 3
```

i expected this to group `test` by `t`, evaluate the `j` statement on each group, and return the rows where `i` is true (that is there is more than 1 unique id). instead what is returned is this:

```
> test
     id t
 1:  1 1
 2:  2 2
 3:  3 1
 4:  4 2
 5:  5 1
 6:  6 2
 7:  7 1
 8:  8 2
 9:  9 1
10: 10 2  
11: 11 3
```

It seems as though the `by` applies to the `j` only and not to `i`.  Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rightly or wrongly, `i` runs first then `j` runs by `by` on all the rows that pass `i`.

A common idiom is something like this (similar to HAVING in SQL) :

```
test[,list(id, u=length(unique(id))), by=t][u>1]
```

and to exclude `u` (the number of unique ids within each group) from the result :

```
test[,list(id, u=length(unique(id))), by=t][u>1][,u:=NULL]
```

Btw, doing vector scans in `i` on (much smaller) aggregated results (such as `u>1` in the line above) is much more efficient than doing vector scans on the (much larger) original data.

If `j` ran by `by` on the whole dataset, followed by `i` on the result (as you expected) then it would cause a problem for efficiency. Consider if it worked that way. Then a filter first followed by grouping on the result would need to be split up into two `[` calls: `DT[i][,j,by]`. Then `i` doesn't see `j` (within `[.data.table`) and doesn't know which columns it needs. Combining it into one `DT[i,j,by]` allows `i` to inspect `j` before evaluation and only subset the columns that `j` needs.  This makes a very large difference in large datasets on queries which use a small subset of the columns.

---

To see what happened, take your `i` and make it `j` :

```
test[,length(unique(id))>1]  
# [1] TRUE
```

Then the single `TRUE` was recycled. `DT[TRUE] == DT`.   You can always test `i` by making it `j` like that.